# How to draw rectangles around every blue object?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have found lots of information about how to draw rectangles around the biggest blue object in the frame but I need to draw rectangles around all of the blue objects.

This is my current code

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2  

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # define range of blue color in HSV
    lower_blue = np.array([100,50,50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])
    # Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
    mask = cv2.inRange (hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    bluecnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(),
                              cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                              cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]


    if len(bluecnts)>0:
        blue_area = max(bluecnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        print(blue_area)
        (xg,yg,wg,hg) = cv2.boundingRect(blue_area)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(xg,yg),(xg+wg, yg+hg),(0,255,0),2)

    result = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('blue', result)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And this is what it currently does, draw one rectangle around the biggest blue object but I need it around each one.

[image: One Blue Rectangle]

Comment: Add a for loop over each contour. Then for each contour get the contour area for that one contour and its bounding box.

Comment: @fmw42 Would you mind giving me the specifics of that code? I think the problem is where the "max" is but I do not know what to replace it with as I am pretty new to machine learning. This is what I tried but got the same result as before ```for object in bluecnts:
        item_area = max(bluecnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        (xg,yg,wg,hg) = cv2.boundingRect(item_area)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(xg,yg),(xg+wg, yg+hg),(0,255,0),2)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Python/OpenCV code, try replacing

```
   if len(bluecnts)>0:
        blue_area = max(bluecnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        print(blue_area)
        (xg,yg,wg,hg) = cv2.boundingRect(blue_area)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(xg,yg),(xg+wg, yg+hg),(0,255,0),2)
```

with

```
   if len(bluecnts)>0:
        for cnt in bluecnts:
            area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
            print(area)
            (xg,yg,wg,hg) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            cv2.rectangle(frame,(xg,yg),(xg+wg, yg+hg),(0,255,0),2)
```

(Untested)